# Get scope identity from generated TableAdapter

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net, dataset, identity-column

When I create a table adapter in Visual Studio, I can click on advanced options and select these options...

[image]

Maybe my assumption is wrong, but it would make sense for me to retrieve that identity column value somehow. I looked at the auto-generated Insert() function for the table adapter, and the integer it returns is the result of ExecuteNonQuery() which is rows affected.

Can someone explain the use of this checkbox? And how I can use it to retrieve the identity of the row inserted?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the table needs a primary key on the database, otherwise there are no update commands generated and the DataTable is not refreshed after inserting (if the key is generated by the database e.g. autoincrement).

If you have no primary key and want to retrieve the values generated by the db, use the OUTPUT clause:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (columnnames ..) 
OUTPUT inserted.* 
VALUES (values...)
```

br

Answer (score 0):

The system is designed to work with a datatable,  So if you want to add a single row one method is to

1. Create a temporary data table,
2. Use the explicit AddRow method of that datatable to add your data
3. Use a table adapter to update the newly created datatable
4. Return the ID field of the first row of the table.

Step 3 actually does the insert, then does a select on the SCOPE_IDENTITY() to refresh all the fields, including the 'ID' column.

A Working example from a WCF:

```
public string AddABCrecord(_ABCrecord ABC)
{
    bool isValid = (ABC.Activity != null) && (ABC.Behaviour != null) && (ABC.Consequence != null);

    DS.__ABCrecordDataTable dt = new DS.__ABCrecordDataTable();
    dt.Add__ABCrecordRow(ABC.Session, ABC.Section, ABC.Video, ABC.Ordinal,
        ABC.Name, ABC.Date, ABC.Time, ABC.Location, ABC.Activity,
        ABC.Antecedent, ABC.Behaviour, ABC.Consequence,
        isValid);

    try
    {
        new ta__ABCrecord().Update(dt);
        return dt[0].ID.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error Adding ABC record\r\n" + e.Message + ((e.InnerException == null) ? "" : Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```